# Fetch from DB via Spring Repository and Service without Session

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, restful-authentication

I've got an authentication filter working in my spring application thanks to  [K. Potgieter's implementation](https://github.com/kevinpotgieter/example-spring-rest-authentication). However, the filter so far only uses a repository that does not connect to any DB but just returns hard coded values. I'm now trying to fetch the user details (name and api key) from the DB.

The problem is that, whenever I autowire the repository from the service class, the autowire fails. The repository I have relies on Spring-data-REST since I would like, in the future, to also expose the user details from a REST API:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserSecurityRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {
    public Users findByUsername(@Param("uname") String name);    
    public Users findByApiKey(@Param("key") String apiKey);    
}
```

from the authentication provider I call the service:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider;
public class RESTDaoAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String apiKey, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        UserDetails loadedUser;
        try {
            loadedUser = this.getUserSecurityService().loadUserByApiKey(apiKey);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException | UserNotFoundException notFound) {
            throw notFound;
        } catch (Exception repositoryProblem) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(repositoryProblem.getMessage(), repositoryProblem);
        }
        if (loadedUser == null) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                    "UserSecurityServiceImpl returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
        }
        return loadedUser;
    }
```

The service then calls the repository (code pasted above) to fetch users by API key from the DB:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserSecurityServiceImpl extends UserDetailsService {
 @Autowired
    private UserSecurityRepository userSecurityRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByApiKey(String apiKey) throws UserNotFoundException {
UserDetails userDetails = buildUserDetails(userSecurityRepository.findByApiKey(apiKey));
        if (userDetails == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User could not be found with the supplied api key.");
        }
        return userDetails;
    }
```

However, this fetch fails since the autowire of the repository from the service class fails. I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSecurityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private mypackage.dal.UserSecurityRepository mypackage.services.UserSecurityServiceImpl.userSecurityRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [mypackage.dal.UserSecurityRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
...
```

I shall not use Session objects to access the DB because I want my app to be stateless and I declared in the security.xml *sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"* as you can see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
    <sec:http disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="forbiddenEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" create-session="never">
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
        <sec:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
    </sec:http>    
    <bean id="forbiddenEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>    
    <sec:authentication-manager alias="defaultAuthenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>    
    <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="mypackage.dal.security.RESTDaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userSecurityService" ref="userSecurityServiceImpl"/>
        <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="mypackagedal.security.authentication.HMacShaPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg name="strength" value="256"/>
        <constructor-arg name="encodeHashAsBase64" value="true"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="restAuthenticationFilter" class="mypackage.dal.security.RESTAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="defaultFilterProcessesUrl" value="/"/>
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="defaultAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
            <!-- Upon successful authentication, Spring will attempt to try and move you to another URL -->
            <!-- We have to prevent this because the request for the resource and the authentication all get done in the same request! -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
                <property name="redirectStrategy">
                    <bean class="mypackage.dal.security.NoRedirectStrategy"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

So, how can I fetch those user data from the DB using Repository and Service and no session objects?

Thank you deeply to whomever will be so kind to help me.

**P.S.**
I'm using Hibernate, Liquibase and Hsqldb. My application context follows below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true" />
    <!--<mvc:annotation-driven/>-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    </bean>

    <import resource="security-context.xml"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/sdrdb" />
        <property name="username" value="SA" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <!--    <bean id="sessionFactory" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" 
        depends-on="flywayAutomaticMigrationBean">-->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="mypackage.dal.entities" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!--    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> -->

</beans>
```

**ATTEMPT 2:**
This time I've tried not to use RestRepository anymore and to use Spring Data JPA instead. However, I still get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when injecting dependencies. Now my repository is as follows:

```
@Repository
public class JpaUserSecurityRepositoryImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    public Users findByUsername(String name) {
        Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT users FROM Users WHERE name =:name");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        return (Users) query.getSingleResult();
    }

    public Users findByApiKey(String apiKey) {
        Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT users FROM Users WHERE api_key =:key");
        query.setParameter("key", apiKey);
        return (Users) query.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

and my @Service accesses the repository as follows:

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityServiceImpl implements UserSecurityService {


    private UserSecurityRepository repository;


    @Autowired
    public UserSecurityServiceImpl(UserSecurityRepository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }
```

I get this NoSuchBeanDefinitionException error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaUserSecurityRepositoryImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

**ATTEMPT 3:**

This time I gave up my wish to have no session created so I tried to use SessionFactory from the repository. I commented out the line in security.xml that was saying

```
<!--<sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>-->
```

and from my service I access the following autowired repository (the autowire works):

```
@Repository
public class DataProviderImpl {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public List<Users> getUsers() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        //I also tried: Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query query = session.createQuery("from Users u");
        return query.list();
    }

    public Users findByUsername(String name) {
        List<Users> allusers = getUsers();
        for (Users user : allusers) {
            if (user.getFirstName().equals(name)) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Please note
**Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
//I also tried: Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();**
from the code above.

It compiles and deploys but when I open a page, rather then getting Authentication failed: wrong key etc. I get Authentication Failed: Cannot open connection when I try sessionFactory.openConnection()
while I get 
*Authentication Failed: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here*
when I try Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); from within the repository.

I'd truly love to manage to fetch these data from my DB somehow. Any help would be super-appreciated! Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

Based on your first attempt, what are the contents of the `default-spring-context.xml`? Does the component-scan include your package? I would have thought that the `@RepositoryRestResource` declaration would have made this bean available to you, but I've not used spring-data-REST before, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you so much! also thanks for the very useful implementation you shared on github ;) My context.xml is in the "P.S" section of my post above (before attempt2 and attempt3..I appreciate that post may contain too much info but I wanted to be as detailed as possible).

Comment: To make things a little simpler to solve this, how about trying to create your own implementation of the `UserSecurityRepository` interface. I'm wondering if the repository interface is whats confusing things here - although I would have thought it should work. Look at the `FakeUserSecurityRepositoryImpl` class for guidance. Just inject a JdbcTemplate and do actual queries through it like that.

Comment: Thanks Kevin but in both attemp2 and attempt3 I provide my own repository, using an entitymanager and a sessionfactory, respectively